# In AIX lsdev -C -c processor command how do we understand the number of processors and cores available?

Tags: aix

```
proc0 Available 00-00 Processor
proc4 Available 00-04 Processor
```

The above mentioned command gives me the following output. So from this how do we find the number of processors and cores available?

Comment: Is it an AIX lpar, wpar or no virtualization?

Comment: It's logical partition

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an lpar, try:

`lparstat -i | grep CPU`

Comment: Online Virtual CPUs                        : 2
Maximum Virtual CPUs                       : 8
Minimum Virtual CPUs                       : 1
Maximum Physical CPUs in system            : 16
Active Physical CPUs in system             : 16
Active CPUs in Pool                        : 16
Shared Physical CPUs in system             : 16
Physical CPU Percentage                    : 10.00%
Desired Virtual CPUs                       : 2

Comment: The above is the output so can you explain those stuff? Even from the documentation its not full clear!!!!

Comment: You have to dive a bit in the docs, I might not be very precise. I'll give a quick explanation: It's an lpar (a vm essentially, in IBM's terminology), so vCPUs are presented to it. This lpar can have 1-8 vCPUs. It has 2 vCPUs currently. It can use 1 Physical cpu from the hypervisor, which has 16 physical cpus available. These 16 physical CPUs can be shared between lpars (they could be dedicated). It could be easier to understand all these if you check the lpar's profile in PowerVM console, along with IBM redbooks of course.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the nonsequential numbering scheme, I found this, then I found this:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-aix-lsdev-cc-processor-output-defined-vs-available-state

*...it is a side effect of moving from a processor type that supports four threads per core to one that supports eight threads per core...*

So you have two virtual processors allocated to the LPAR, but they aren't numbered sequentially because of a former change in processor type.

Tipp: AIX 7 includes nmon in AIX Perf Tools, so type nmon then press "p", it shows you all about processor allocation and the assigned processor pool